# AngularJS ng-repeat conflicting with jquery

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have an angularjs code below which works very fine to display a record from database. Because the content is lengthy, I want to add **read more** button via jquery. If I call the jquery data outside the **angularjs ng-repeat** function, the **ReadMore button** works. eg

```
<div class="text">
Hi! Introducing myself as wasco man. I am an arena where people can visit by typing wasco from any where in the world. The purpose of my birth is to give solutions in all ramifications. Coming to my work is a web designer and a developer who has got vast experience in giving solutions
 on JQuery, Ajax and PHP from small websites to big portals and high performing enterprise web applications. The innet passion to teach people has provoked him to introduce me to this world to fulfill his desire.

     <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>
    </div>
```

But the problem now is that when I tried to call the Jquery Data within the **angularjs ng-repeat** function, the readmore button  does not work. It seems that angularjs is conflicting with jquery as in the code below

```
       <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>
 <div class="text">
    Hi! Introducing myself as wasco man. I am an arena where people can visit by typing wasco from any where in the world. The purpose of my birth is to give solutions in all ramifications. Coming to my work is a web designer and a developer who has got vast experience in giving solutions
     on JQuery, Ajax and PHP from small websites to big portals and high performing enterprise web applications. The innet passion to teach people has provoked him to introduce me to this world to fulfill his desire.

        </div> </div>
```

Below is the entircode..

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>

        <link href="style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />



<!--read more text starts here-->

 <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

 function breakWords(paragraph, showtext){


  var words = paragraph.split(' ');

  var newText = '';

  for(i=0; i<words.length; i++){


   if(i<= showtext){

    newText += words[i] + ' ';

   }else {

    if (i == (showtext + 1)) newText += '... <span class="fulltext hide">';  

    newText += words[i] + ' ';

    if (words[i+1] == null) newText += '</span><a href="#" class="links"> &raquo; read more</a>';

   }

  }

  return newText;

 }


 $('.text').each(function () {

   $(this).html(breakWords($(this).html(), 50));

   $(this).children('span').hide();


  }).click(function () {


   var fulltext = $(this).children('span.fulltext');
   var links = $(this).children('a.links');


   if (fulltext.hasClass('hide')) {

    fulltext.show(200);
    links.html(' &raquo; hide');  
    fulltext.removeClass('hide');

   } else {

    fulltext.fadeOut(100);
    links.html(' &laquo; read more');   
    fulltext.addClass('hide');

   }

   return false;

  });

});

</script>


<!--read more text ends-->

    </head>
    <body ng-app='myapp'>
        <div class="content" ng-controller='fetchCtrl' >

            <div class="post" ng-repeat='post in posts'>



<div class="text">
Hi! Introducing myself as wasco man. I am an arena where people can visit by typing wasco from 
any where in the world. 

The purpose of my birth is to give solutions in all ramifications. 

Coming to my work is a web designer and a developer who has got vast experience in giving solutions
 on JQuery, Ajax and PHP from small websites to big portals and high performing enterprise web
 applications. The innet passion to teach people has provoked him to introduce me to this world to fulfill his desire. 
Thanks a lot !!!</div>


                <h1 >{{ post.title }}</h1>
                <div class="post-text">
                    {{ post.content }}
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Script -->
        <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
        <script>
        var fetch = angular.module('myapp', []);
        fetch.controller('fetchCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http) {

                // Fetch post data
                $scope.getPosts = function(){

                    $http({
                        method: 'post',
                        url: 'likeunlike.php',
                        data: {request: 1}
                    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                        $scope.posts = response.data;
                    });

                }

                $scope.getPosts(); // Fetch post data

            }
        ]);

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Why-we-should-not-use-jQuery-in-AngularJS

Comment: Don't even use jQuery. Don't even include it. It will hold you back. And when you come to a problem that you think you know how to solve in jQuery already, before you reach for the $, try to think about how to do it within the confines the AngularJS. If you don't know, ask! 19 times out of 20, the best way to do it doesn't need jQuery and to try to solve it with jQuery results in more work for you.